# Angular2 input with ngFor

Tags: angular, input, ionic2, ngfor

Hello everyone I'd like to send select option data from ngFor to Ts file but I tried [attr.value] , (ngModelChange) (change) all of them sent data's name only  I want to send the all data which comes from ngFor

**Html**

```
<select [(ngModel)]="event" 
  class="selectpicker show-menu-arrow form-control show-tick" 
  data-style="btn-primary" (change)="doSomething(event)">

  <option *ngFor="let event of events|filter:search" 
    EventInput="{{event}}" 
    [attr.value]="event2">
    {{event.eventName}}
  </option>

</select>
```

**TS**

```
@Input('EventInput') EventInput: any;

doSomething(event) {
    console.log("optValue: ", event);
    //this.eventDetailsPageSend(event);
    console.log("input: ", this.EventInput);
}
```

the optValue comes only name of event but I need the all data like id,etc(how comes from ngFor) so that I can push another page.I don't know if i should use Input or ngModelChange for being new with angular and this issue

Thank you.

Comment: You can't. The value of an option is a string only. Either you can use `JSON.stringify` to pass all your object into the value (which I don't recommend), or you use Array methods such as `find`, `filter` or `reduce` in your change function.

Comment: Thank you for your quick reply , can you please give a brief example for change function

Comment: No I can't sorry, because I REALLY don't understand your code and your explanation. Plus, it's missing some parts of it, like your `events` property.

Comment: Thank you for your quick reply.

Comment: Well no problem. If you want a start, try doing this in your change function : `this.events.filter(ev => console.log(ev))` and see how you can compare your `event` variable to this `ev`

Comment: Just adding [ngValue] to option solved.Thanks to ngValue , option returns an object that I want.

Answer (score 3):

I dont know what you meen "I'd like to send select option data from ngFor to Ts file". So I'll assume what you want ;].
If you want to set the `value` of the `<option>` tag you should do

```
<select (change)="changed()" [(ngModel)]="selected">
   <option value=""></option>
   <option *ngFor="let event of events" [ngValue]="event">
     {{event.name}}
   </option>
</select>
```

In the component add

```
public selected = {};
public changed() {
  console.log(this.selected);
}
```

Dont forget to import `FormsModule` in AppModule `@NgModule`

Also I dont know where has setted your `@Input` decorator, but you can share data via `@Input` attributes only from `Parent` -> `Child` component, another thing is that in Angular2/4 there's no build in `filter` pipe anymore.

Edited

Comment: Thank you for your reply,
I installed ng2-search-filter which is available for Angular 2 / Angular 4 .What I mean is I get the data from ngFor {{event of events}} I want to send this all event data which includes id,name,adress. But option sends only the name of event

Comment: It helped me a lot I solved with [ngValue] Thank you.